# Best way to represent edge on a graph

Tags: java, graph

what is the best way to represent an edge on a directed graph? I represent it by create a class Node and in this class I define a list that contains the connected nodes of that node. The edge is represented by a tuple (start,end) and (start,end) != (end,start)

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Node<T> {

    public T data;

    public List<T> children; // here there are the neighbors

    public Node(T data) {
        this.data = data;
        this.children = new LinkedList<>();
    }

    public T getData() {
        return data;
   }

    public LinkedList<T> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }
}
```

I am saying that because I want to find the shortest path from source and destination but it's hard to understand how to do it and how to avoid cycles etc. I know that there is Dijkstra algorithm but it's for weighted graph. I have to represent a directed graph without weight.

Comment: Dijkstra's algorithm works on unweighted graphs, too.

Comment: The "best" way is to not re-invent the wheel and use embedded mode of OrientDB or Neo4j

Comment: @aryamccarthy where can I find the pseudo-code? thanks!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#Pseudocode

Comment: Neo4j has a `shortestPath` function, by the way... http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/match/#query-shortest-path

Comment: Are you asking the way to represent edges of a graphs? or how to calculate shortest path? those are two different question